# Exporting data to a CSV file from multiple Arrays

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv

I am trying to export a number of arrays to a CSV File. The array contains a list of string value which I then have to put them into separate columns on a CSV file.

I have used 'hash table' and 'PSCustomObject' but I am not sure if this is the correct way to do it.
The closest I can do is to retrieve one array and use 'Export-Csv' placing the data to one column.

Is there a way to put multiple array values to separate columns?

This work as expected:

```
$RegexValueOne | ForEach-Object {[PSCustomObject] @{ColumnOne = $_}} Export-Csv c:\users\username\desktop\regexdata.csv
```

Below is what I have attempted exporting more than one array to separate CSV columns:

```
$ValueOne = $RegexValueOne | ForEach-Object {[PSCustomObject] @{ColumnOne = $_}} 
$ValueTwo = $RegexValueTwo | ForEach-Object {[PSCustomObject] @{ColumnTwo = $_}}

$RegexData = [PSCustomObject]@{
    RegexColumnOne     = $ValueOne
    RegexColumnTwo     = $ValueTwo 



  }
$RegexData | Export-Csv c:\users\username\desktop\regexdata.csv
```

Comment: Does each array have the same number of items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume `$RegexValueOne` and `$RegexValueTwo` are your arrays, you can choose any of the following scenarios:

If each array has the same number of rows, you can loop through the index numbers simultaneously on multiple arrays.

```
0..($RegexValueOne.Count-1) | Foreach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        RegexColumnOne = $RegexValueOne[$_]
        RegexColumnTwo = $RegexValueTwo[$_]
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path 'c:\users\username\desktop\regexdata.csv' -NoType
```

---

If each array has a different number of rows, you will need to determine how many indexes to iterate. This works if you are not running PowerShell in strict mode as the indexes without values will be null in the custom object.

```
$MaxIndex = [math]::Max($RegexValueOne.Count,$RegexValueTwo.Count)-1
0..$MaxIndex | Foreach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{ RegexColumnOne = $RegexValueOne[$_]
                       RegexColumnTwo = $RegexValueTwo[$_]
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path 'c:\users\username\desktop\regexdata.csv' -NoType
```

---

If each array has an undetermined number of indexes and null index errors will be thrown, you can do the following:

```
$MaxIndexes = ($RegexValueOne.Count-1),($RegexValueTwo.Count-1)
$MaxIndex = [math]::Max($MaxIndexes[0],$MaxIndexes[1])
0..$MaxIndex | Foreach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{ 
        RegexColumnOne = if ($MaxIndexes[0] -ge $_) { $RegexValueOne[$_] } else { '' }
        RegexColumnTwo = if ($MaxIndexes[1] -ge $_) { $RegexValueTwo[$_] } else { '' }
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path 'c:\users\username\desktop\regexdata.csv' -NoType
```

---

**Explanation:**

Since arrays are indexed starting with `0`, you can access individual elements using the syntax `$array[index]`. We need to know the highest index number that contains data so that we can loop effectively and efficiently.

Using [Foreach-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7), we are utilizing the pipeline. The current pipeline item is `$_`. Using the pipeline, allows us to export to csv optimally.

The range [operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7) (`..`) is a short way to make a sequential integer array.

Comment: AdminOfThings - Thanks for explaining this very detailed, the third example did the trick.